# Radialgradiant in SVG not working in Edge

Tags: css, svg, microsoft-edge, radial-gradients

I have made a map in `svg`-format where every province is a `path`. Every province (`path`) has te same `fill`-color. I have created a hover-effect where the province that is hovered receives a `radialgradient`. I have defined the `gradient` inside the `svg`-tags in my `html`:

```
<defs>
    <radialgradient id="HoverGradient">
        <stop  stop-color="var(--ivory)" offset="0%"/>
        <stop  stop-color="var(--province-fill)" offset="100%"/>
    </radialgradient>

    <filter id="shadow" x="0" y="0" width="200%" height="200%">
        <feDropShadow dx="5" dy="5" stdDeviation="10" flood-color="var(--text-color)" flood-opacity="1" />
    </filter>
</defs>
```

I am handling the `hover` in my `css`:

```
.province{
    fill: var(--province-fill); /* which is blue rgba(2, 20, 94, .9)*/
    stroke: white;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.province:hover{
    fill: url("#HoverGradient");
    filter: url("#shadow");
}
```

It is working fine in Chrome but not in Edge. In Edge the province completely disappears on hover.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Edge Legacy for testing? I don't know how you define the `<path>` and `<filter>`, I made a simple example and it can work well in Edge Legacy. You can check [this sample](https://jsfiddle.net/awm5oxt4/4/) in Edge. I suggest you to provide a code snippet which can **reproduce** the issue including how you define the `<path>` and `<filter>`, so that we can have a test and see how to help.

Comment: @Yu Zhou. I edited my question to add my `<filter>` to the `<defs>`. When I replace your `<filter>` with mine in the fiddle, it does not work anymore in Edge. So that seems to be where problem is. Hope you can help me with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: ICT department tells me we work with a very old version of Edge (44). The drop-shadow is not supported. Thanks for you help anyway.

Comment: Yes, `<feDropShadow>` is [not supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feDropShadow#Browser_compatibility) by Edge Legacy. You can update to the latest Edge browser and use it in Edge Chromium.